# Angular JS directive with JQuery Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, format, iso

I'm totally new to angular js. But I somehow managed to integrate a jQuery UI datepicker in my Angular JS project.
But now I want to format the date picked by the jQuery datepicker into ISO date format which I'm not being able to do.
Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="event.when.start" datetime-picker>
```

**ANGULAR Controller**

```
myApp.directive('datetimePicker', function() {
   return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $(function(){
                element.datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                    minDate: 0,
                    yearRange: '1920:2012',
                    minute: 0,
                    stepMinute: 15,
                    onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {
                        var dt = new Date(dateText);
                        alert(dt.toISOString());
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(dt.toISOString());
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

**Note*: I'm being able to alert the value though.**

Comment: Try this post example http://www.freakyjolly.com/jquery-ui-datepicker-directive-angularjs-min-max-options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply as below

```
myapp.controller('myctrl',function myctrl ($scope){
    $scope.event = {when : {start : ''}}
    $scope.event.when.start = new Date();
}).

    myApp.directive('datetimePicker', function() {
       return {
            require : 'ngModel',
            link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                $(function(){
                    element.datetimepicker({
                        minDate: 0,
                        yearRange: '1920:2012',
                        minute: 0,
                        stepMinute: 15,
                        onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {

                            scope.$apply(function(){
                               scope.event.when.start = new Date(dateText);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

don't use `dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',` if you need ISO Date

Comment: thank you for the answer @bews99. It works! :) but for that i need to click twice on the datepicker. Is it possible to format the date when i focus on that input field.

Comment: I edited my comment above. As i said, it is working but i need to click twice on the date of datepicker, to make it work.

Comment: my project requires lots of other js and css. I'm not being able to put it in jsfiddle. is there any other way?

Comment: updated answer.check wrap your code inside scope.$apply

Comment: still not working as required @bews99 :( Actually, when i focus on input field, the datepicker automatically fills up the field with the default now time. Which I want it to be filled with ISO formatted datetime. Could you please help me with that. I heartly appreciate your help.

Comment: then initialize the ng-model inside the controller function which directive is hold. updated answer.but i am still confused about what you are telling and what you really want.